# Использование переменной в теле формулы в макросе VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Есть переменная "С" - в макросе это номер строки.
Макросом необходимо вставить формулы следующего вида:

```
1) FormulaLocal = "=O1-T1"
```

При этом всесто "1" должна использоваться переменная "С"
Пробовал вот так:

```
FormulaLocal = ""=O" &C& "-T"&C&"""
```

ругается на синтаксис.

```
2) FormulaLocal= "=T1/(O1*100)"
```

Аналогично, пробовал написать код следующим образом:

```
FormulaLocal = = ""=T"&C&"/(O"&C&"*100)""
```

пишет "*Expected end of statement*"

Подскажите, как синтаксически корректно оформить скрипт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FormulaLocal = = ""=T"&C&"/(O"&C&"*100)""**

1. Явная ошибка - лишний знак "равно".
2. Вторая ошибка - в данном случае двойные кавычки не нужны.

Здесь формула - текст, который при выполнении кода будет преобразован в формулу и записан на лист. Текст - часть кода, заключаемая в кавычки. Кавычки могут присутствовать и внутри текста. Такие кавычки пишутся двойными, чтобы показать, что они не являются гранцами текста:

```
sStr = "ООО ""Рога и Копыта"" забодало налоговую"
```

Текст может быть составлен из нескольких фрагментов, каждый из которых заключается в кавычки:

```
sStr = "ООО " & """Рога и Копыта"" забодало" & " налоговую"
```

3. Оператор дожен  быть оператором, а не служебным символом.

Символ & - знак конкатенации, оператор объединения. Если символ не отделить пробелами от сцепляемых фрагментов, редактор будет ругаться - оператор должен быть записан отдельно:

```
Cells(5, 1).FormulaLocal = "=T" & C & "/(O" & C & "*100)"
```

Но & - это и служебный символ, обозначающий тип переменной *Long*. В этом случае переменная и символ типа нераздельны:

```
Dim i&
i& = Sheets.Count
такая запись тоже правильна: 
Cells(5, 1).FormulaLocal = "=T" & C& & "/(O" & C& & "*100)"
```

4. Не ошибка. *FormulaLocal* - если требуется записать формулу с функциями локальной версии. Для простых формул достаточно *Formula* или *FormulaR1C1*
5. Почти ошибка. *С* - зарезервированный символ, указатель столбца в ссылках формата *R1C1*. Нужно избегать применения зарезервированных символов для обозначения переменных, иначе возможны конфликты.

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Formula = "=O" & C & " - T" & C & ""

.Formula = "=T" & C & "/(O" & C & "*100)"
```